# MVCAwesome, MVC4 and NuGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

I created a new MVC4 project using Razor syntax, and used NuGet to add MVCAwesome.

Looking at [this page](http://awesome.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation), it appears that all the expected files and configuration files appear to be in place. I made the edit to the Views/Web.config as directed.

When I try to reference any Awe() controls however, the reference to Awe() shows up in red text, and I get an error message: **Cannot resolve symbol Awe()**

```
@Html.Awe().DatePickerFor(model => model.BirthDate).ChangeMonth(true).ChangeYear(true)
```

Has anyone gotten this to work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, I was able to contact the maintainer of this library. It turns out that in this newer, NuGet version of the controls, you don't need the Awe() part.

For some reason, DatePickerFor still seems to be missing, but I do see other controls there from the package.